# AJAX call to grab contents of a textarea in a modal window after the DOM loads

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm using [Messi](http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/) for modal windows. In this case, I added a text area to the modal window but cannot access the value in it since the DOM has already loaded. My current code is as follows:

```
        new Messi('<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x pull-left"></i><strong>Send a message to ' + co + '. </strong><br />Check the Messages tab to converse with  ' + co + '.'
            + '<label class="textarea">'
            + '<textarea id="themessage" name="notes" placeholder="Enter Message" rows="5" style="margin-top:11px"></textarea>'
            + '</label>'
            + '<div class="note">Enter Message</div>', {
            title: 'Message ' + co ,
            titleClass: '',
            modal: true,
            closeButton: true,
            unload:false,
            buttons: [{
                id: 0,
                label: 'Send Message',
                class: '',
                val: 'Y'
            }],
            callback: function (val) {
                if (val === 'Y') {
                    var themsg = $("textarea#themessage").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'controller.php',
                        data: {
                            'processMessage': id,
                            'recipient':recipient,
                            'company': co,
                            'msgsubject':msgsubject,
                            'body': themsg,
                            'title':encodeURIComponent(name)
                        },
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            parent.animate({
                                'backgroundColor': '#FFF'
                            }, 400);
                        },
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: 0
                            }, 600);
                            $('#msgholder').html(decodeURIComponent(msg));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
```

In the callback function, I try grabbing the value but no luck there

```
var themsg = $("textarea#themessage").val();
```

I also tried including this when setting variables in the initial click function to invoke the modal window but it's not working since the DOM is loaded prior to the modal text area being edited.

```
 $('body').on('click', 'a.mod-button', function () {
                var themsg = $("textarea#themessage").val();
                console.log(themsg);
            });
```

How can I grab the newly typed in text when the user clicks Submit in the modal window?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using

```
var themsg = $("#themessage").val();
```

instead of:

```
var themsg = $("textarea#themessage").val();
```

If the textbox already has a Id="themessage" I think the callback is looking for that element.